# In App Purchase: Detecting whether a feature has already been purchased in another device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, in-app-purchase

Apple demands that the features sold on In App Purchase are available for all the devices of the user. Currently, my app asks the NSUserDefaults singleton if the feature is available, when the user bought the feature from the same device it works great, the problem is that the other devices the user may have are not aware of this purchase until they repeat the purchase process and the store tell them so.

So I was wondering if this is OK. If not, what should I implement to detect this information?

Comment: @Milkywan - Please consider selecting some answers where appropriate. You'll find people more eager to help you if you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Store Kit framework provides support to restore nonconsumable products on additional devices. The In App Purchase Programming Guide has the details but you basically call restoreCompletedTransactions and get back the previous transactions.

You can also allow the user to repeat the purchase on each new device though you might want to make it clear to the user that they will only be charged once.